# How to implement a delay timer that flip useState(true) to useState(false) in react js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Im currently learning on tutorials of a project and they uses React Js for front end. This is my first time working on a react js so Im really confused on how to implement conditions of flipping:

'setShowAnimation' from true to false with a delay timer of 3 sec under the condition where 'setShowAnimation == true'. Any reference / guide is much appreciated!

```
const App = () => {
...
const [showAnimation, setShowAnimation] = useState(false);
...
   const wave = async () => {
     try {
   .......
     const waveTxn = await wavePortalContract.wave(tweetValue,{gasLimit:300000});
     console.log("Mining...", waveTxn.hash);

     setShowAnimation(true);
     .....
   }

React.useEffect(() => {
  const timeout = setTimeout(() => {
    setShowAnimation(false)
    },3000)
  return () => clearTimeout(timeout)
}, [showAnimation])

}
```

Answer (score 1):

you have to add a condition if it needs to be run only when `showAnimation` is true.

```
React.useEffect(() => {
    if(showAnimation){
       const timeout = setTimeout(() => {
          setShowAnimation(false)
       },3000)
       return () => clearTimeout(timeout)
     }
}, [showAnimation])
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply.
Does by default if(showAnimation) means if (showAnimation === true) ?

Comment: yes, that means.